# Multithreading and Monitoring

Tags: multithreading, monitoring

I am trying to get multithreading more unraveled in my head. I made these three classes.

A global variable class

```
public partial class globes
{
    public bool[] sets = new bool[] { false, false, false };
    public bool boolChanged = false;
    public string tmpStr = string.Empty;
    public int gcount = 0;
    public bool intChanged = false;
    public Random r = new Random();
    public bool gDone = false;
    public bool first = true;
}
```

Drop in point

```
class Driver
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("start");

            globes g = new globes();

            Thread[] threads = new Thread[6];
            ParameterizedThreadStart[] pts = new ParameterizedThreadStart[6];

            lockMe _lockme = new lockMe();

            for (int b = 0; b < 3; b++)
            {
                pts[b] = new ParameterizedThreadStart(_lockme.paramThreadStarter);
                threads[b] = new Thread(pts[b]);
                threads[b].Name = string.Format("{0}", b);
                threads[b].Start(b);
            }
        }
    }
```

And then my threading class

```
class lockMe
    {
        #region Fields

        private string[] words = new string[] {"string0", "string1", "string2", "string3"};
        private globes g = new globes();
        private object myKey = new object();

        private string[] name = new string[] { String.Empty, String.Empty, String.Empty };

        #endregion

        #region methods

        // first called for all threads
        private void setName(Int16 i)
        {
            Monitor.Enter(myKey);
            {
                try
                {
                    name[i] = string.Format("{0}:{1}", Thread.CurrentThread.Name, g.r.Next(100, 500).ToString());
                }
                finally
                {
                    Monitor.PulseAll(myKey);
                    Monitor.Exit(myKey);
                }
            }
        }

        // thread 1
        private void changeBool(Int16 a)
        {
            Monitor.Enter(myKey);
            {
                try
                {
                    int i = getBools();
                    //Thread.Sleep(3000);
                    if (g.gcount > 5) { g.gDone = true; return; }
                    if (i == 3) resets();
                    else { for (int x = 0; x <= i; i++) { g.sets[x] = true; } }

                    Console.WriteLine("Thread {0} ran through changeBool()\n", name[a]);
                }
                finally
                {
                    Monitor.PulseAll(myKey);
                    Monitor.Exit(myKey);
                }
            }
        }

        // thread 2
        private void changeInt(Int16 i)
        {
            Monitor.Enter(myKey);
            {
                try
                {
                    g.gcount++;
                    //Thread.Sleep(g.r.Next(1000, 3000));
                    Console.WriteLine("Thread {0}: Count is now at {1}\n", name[i], g.gcount);
                }
                finally
                {
                    Monitor.PulseAll(myKey);
                    Monitor.Exit(myKey);
                }
            }
        }

        // thread 3
        private void printString(Int16 i)
        {
            Monitor.Enter(myKey);
            {
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("...incoming...");
                    //Thread.Sleep(g.r.Next(1500, 2500));
                    Console.WriteLine("Thread {0} printing...{1}\n", name[i], words[g.r.Next(0, 3)]);
                }
                finally
                {
                    Monitor.PulseAll(myKey);
                    Monitor.Exit(myKey);
                }
            }
        }

        // not locked- called from within a locked peice
        private int getBools()
        {
            if ((g.sets[0] == false) && (g.sets[1] == false) && (g.sets[2] == false)) return 0;
            else if ((g.sets[0] == true) && (g.sets[1] == false) && (g.sets[2] == false)) return 1;
            else if ((g.sets[2] == true) && (g.sets[3] == false)) return 2;
            else if ((g.sets[0] == true) && (g.sets[1] == true) && (g.sets[2] == true)) return 3;
            else return 99;
        }

        // should not need locks- called within locked statement
        private void resets()
        {
            if (g.first) { Console.WriteLine("FIRST!!"); g.first = false; }
            else Console.WriteLine("Cycle has reset...");
        }

        private bool getStatus()
        {
            bool x = false;

            Monitor.Enter(myKey);
            {
                try
                {
                    x = g.gDone;
                }
                finally
                {
                    Monitor.PulseAll(myKey);
                    Monitor.Exit(myKey);
                }
            }

            return x;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Constructors

        public void paramThreadStarter(object starter)
        {
            Int16 i = Convert.ToInt16(starter);
            setName(i);

            do
            {
                switch (i)
                {
                    default: throw new Exception();
                    case 0:
                        changeBool(i);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        changeInt(i);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        printString(i);
                        break;
                }
            } while (!getStatus());

            Console.WriteLine("fin");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

So I have a few questions. The first- is it better to have my global class set like this? Or should I be using a static class with properties and altering them that way? Next question is, when this runs, at random one of the threads will run, pulse/exit the lock, and then step right back in (sometimes like 5-10 times before the next thread picks up the lock). Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each thread is given a certain amount of CPU time, I doubt that one particular thread is getting more actual CPU time over the others if you are locking all the calls in the same fashion and the thread priorities are the same among the threads.

Regarding how you use your global class, it doesn't really matter.  The way you are using it wouldn't change it one way or the other.  Your use of globals was to test thread safety, so when multiple threads are trying to **change shared properties** all that matters is that you enforce thread safety.

Pulse might be a better option knowing that only one thread can actually enter, pulseAll is appropriate when you lock something because you have a task to do, once that task is complete and won't lock the very next time. In your scenario you lock every time so doing a pulseAll is just going to waste cpu because **you know** that it will be locked for the next request.

Common example of when to use static classes and why you must make them thread safe:

```
public static class StoreManager
{
   private static Dictionary<string,DataStore> _cache = new Dictionary<string,DataStore>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

   private static object _syncRoot = new object();

   public static DataStore Get(string storeName)
   {
       //this method will look for the cached DataStore, if it doesn't
       //find it in cache it will load from DB.
       //The thread safety issue scenario to imagine is, what if 2 or more requests for 
       //the same storename come in?  You must make sure that only 1 thread goes to the
       //the DB and all the rest wait...

       //check to see if a DataStore for storeName is in the dictionary
       if ( _cache.ContainsKey( storeName) == false )
       {
           //only threads requesting unknown DataStores enter here...

           //now serialize access so only 1 thread at a time can do this...
           lock(_syncRoot)
           {
               if (_cache.ContainsKey(storeName) == false )
               { 
                  //only 1 thread will ever create a DataStore for storeName
                  DataStore ds = DataStoreManager.Get(storeName); //some code here goes to DB and gets a DataStore
                  _cache.Add(storeName,ds);
               }
           }
       }

       return _cache[storeName];
   }
}
```

What's really important to see is that the `Get` method only single threads the call when there is no DataStore for the storeName.

**Double-Check-Lock:**
  You can see the first lock() happens after an `if`, so imagine 3 threads simultaneously run the `if ( _cache.ContainsKey(storeName) ..`, now all 3 threads enter the if.  Now we lock so that only 1 thread can enter, now we do the same exact `if` statement, only the very first thread that gets here will actually pass this if statement and get the DataStore.  Once the first thread `.Add`'s the DataStore and exits the lock the other 2 threads will fail the second check (double check).

From that point on any request for that storeName will get the cached instance.

So we single threaded our application only in the spots that **required it**.

Comment: I am asking whether or not I should keep it as is, or if I should make it a static class. So instead of having the "private globes g = new glodes();" I would just access it via globes.'property' = 'something';. I am trying to plan for what this will evolve into, and unfortunately there will be other threads that will need to access the global variables not within the 'lockme' class.

Comment: Also, with the threads all getting even CPU... I still am not understanding why one will then release the lock, and then step back into itself (and do so repeatedly). Each thread writes to the console per cycle. In my mind there should be some sort of sequence to it, not the same going through over and over again. Should I be using Pulse() instead of PulseAll()?

Comment: Pulse might be a better option knowing that only one thread can actually enter, pulseAll is appropriate when you lock something because you have a task to do, once that task is complete and won't lock the very next time.  In your scenario you lock every time so doing a pulseAll is just going to waste cpu because **you know** that it will be locked for the next request.

Comment: Great info; thank you! 

Yes you are correct, mainly the 'point' of this class is to verify that my threads are running/accessing safely. I will switch to the Pulse() instead. Is my understanding correct in that I can change 'globes' to be a static class and alter those 'global variables' via it's properties and it will be seen across all threads

Comment: from a thread safety perspective, a single instance of a class (like you have now) that is being shared is ultimately the same as a static class with static properties.  I may be parsing your words but `seen across all threads` isn't the right terminology, all your threads are referring the same instance, so if with one thread you change a property then all the other objects that refer to that instance will have access to it.

Comment: I guess what I meant by that was the usage of a static class kind of off par from their design. From my understanding they are mainly for 'doing something' and not so much data storage correct? I just wanted to make sure that it didn't lose the data- but from your clarification it seems that will be ok

Comment: Static classes are (commonly) used to hold data for cache, I will post an example.  Learn the double-check lock pattern, i will use it in my example... thanks for the upvote!